# Find in a list of tuples the tuple with highest Item1 value - Then remove it from the list

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have a List of tuples of the type:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> listOfStuffs= new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
```

Now, considering I have filled up my list with some useful values, how can I extract from that list (in a different Tuple), the Tuple containing the highest Item1 value?
If there is more than one match, it must return the first one only.

This does not work as it returns an Int value rather than the actual Tuple:

```
Tuple<int, int> selectedTuple = listOfStuffs.Max(t => t.Item1);
```

---

Once we have found that match, how can it be removed from listOfStuffs?

I have done the following thing and it seems to remove only one Tuple from the list (as required) when there are duplicates:

```
listOfStuffs.Remove(new Tuple<int, int>(selectedTuple.Item1, selectedTuple.Item2));
```

Maybe there is a way to combine these operations?

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?  What result do you get instead?

Comment: Please post more code, and exactly what error, or wrong result, are you getting.

Comment: That does not even compile - I just put that line to clarify what I was trying to do, maybe I should not have if that is confusing :-)

Comment: What if multiple tuples have the same `Item1`-value?

Comment: Edited question - Returning an Int rather than a Tuple

Comment: This worked for me: Tuple<int, int> Result = listOfStuffs.Find(t => (t.Item1 == listOfStuffs.Min(u => u.Item1))); ... please note that this is literally the implementation of listOfStuffs.Min().

Comment: Great stuffs, thanks guys!

Comment: @MiguelMateo better to calculate `Min` only once and not for each element. (though I'm sure OP meant `Max` for the "highest Item1" )

Comment: Absolutely agree, better put the min result in a variable instead of letting the compiler doing the optimizations.  The idea was that Find + Min can always be used.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either sort the list and take the first:

```
var tupleWithMaxItem1 = listOfStuffs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1).First();
```

Or you can use [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq)'s `MaxBy()` extension:

```
var tupleWithMaxItem1 = listOfStuffs.MaxBy(x => x.Item1);
```

`MaxBy()` will be faster than sorting the list first.

Answer (score 3):

As `Tuple` implements `IComparable`, you can just use `Max` to get the Tuple with the highest Item1 value:

```
Tuple<int, int> Result = listOfStuffs.Max();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [ArgMax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) which is *not implemented* in *standard* Linq, but can be encoded with a help of `Aggregate`:

```
Tuple<int, int> Result = listOfStuffs.Aggregate((s, a) => s.Item1 > a.Item1 ? s : a);
```

If *several* items have the *same* `Item1` value we return the *first* one; if you want to return the *last* one, change `>` into `>=`:

```
Tuple<int, int> Result = listOfStuffs.Aggregate((s, a) => s.Item1 >= a.Item1 ? s : a);
```